# Growth function of the class of all circles in the plane

Tags: machine-learning, classification, vc-theory

I know that the VC dimension for this problem is 3. My concern is about the growth function. The following bound is obtained using the VC dimension:
$$m_{\mathcal{H}}(n)\le \sum_{k=0}^3\,{n\choose k}$$
When I simulate this hypothesis set up to $n= 10$, the maximum number of dichotomies I obtain is exactly $\sum_{k=0}^{3}\,{n\choose k}$. Is it by coincidence or is there a way to prove this?

Comment: Your question might be more suitable for https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Unfortunately your question is not clear! You have inequality and reach the maximum which satisfies it. You can count all possible dichotomies as well. What do you wanna prove here?

Comment: I reach the maximum for n up to 10, since I can count all possible dichotomies for n up to 10 (I cannot go beyond with my computer). I am asking help for a mathematical proof for all n>0.